# Clipping camera to view moves mesh

Tags: modeling, camera, scene, viewlayers

I've created a mesh and applied a texture over it; after hitting Ctrl + NUMPAD_0 instead of moving the camera to current view the mesh is flipped in front of the camera:

[image]

Also, the camera also appears to have been hidden from the scene collection's viewer.

Who on Earth thought this was a good idea?

Comment: Hello :). *Ctrl + Numpad 0* is to set active object as camera. To align active camera to view, use *Ctrl + Alt + Numpad 0*.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Couldn't find the original camera so I added a new one :P